# Need help with test code

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

I was given this test code on here, and I'm having some problems with it.

UPDATE : This is the current code with the static fix for generateTestUser()

```
public with sharing class AutoCreateSubsTriggerTest {

    static testMethod void testAutoCreateSubs() {
        // First, set up your test User.
        User testUser = generateTestUser();

        // Generate your position but don't perform DML yet
        Contract_Overview__c contover = new Contract_Overview__c(Subsidiaries_On_Contract__c = testUser.Id);

        // Start your test and insert your contract overview
        Test.startTest();
        insert contover;
        Test.stopTest();

        // Get the subs from the DB to ensure they were created
        List<Subs_Serviced_On_Contract__c> subs = [SELECT
                                                 Id
                                             FROM
                                                 Subs_Serviced_On_Contract__c
                                             WHERE
                                                 Contract_Overview__c = :contover.Id
        ];

        // There should be 1 interviewer because only one user ID was provided
        System.assert(1, subs.size(), 'One sub object is expected');
    }

    private static User generateTestUser(){
        // We use the System Admin profile because it will always be there
        Profile sysAdmin = [SELECT 
                               Id 
                            FROM 
                               Profile 
                            WHERE 
                               Name = 'System Administrator'
                            LIMIT 1
        ];

        // Generate the user
        User newUser = new User(
            UserName = 'unit.tester@example.com',
            LastName = 'Test',
            FirstName = 'Jane',
            Email = 'unit.tester@example.com',
            phone = '555-555-5555',
            MobilePhone = '555-555-5554',
            Street = '123 Fake Street',
            City = 'Los Angeles',
            State = 'CA',
            PostalCode = '12345',
            CommunityNickName = 'unit.test',
            Alias = 'abcd',
            ProfileId = sysAdmin.Id,
            emailencodingkey = 'UTF-8',
            languagelocalekey = 'en_US',
            localesidkey = 'en_US',
            timezonesidkey = 'America/Los_Angeles'
        );

        // Insert that user
        insert newuser;

        return newuser;
    }
}
```

....and now I'm getting that same type of error :

```
Save Error : Method does not exist or incorrect siganure: System.assert(Integer, Integer, String)


Save error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: generateTestUser()
```

that is referencing this line (25) :

```
System.assert(1, subs.size(), 'One sub object is expected');
```

One other question, are these lines correct at the bottom :

```
insert newuser;

return newuser;
```

..or should they be :

```
insert user;

insert user;
```

Thanks for everything. I really appreciate the time & effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

generateTestUser() is not a static method so you cannot call it from your static test method.  Either make generateTestUser() static (preferred I would think) or create an instance of AutoCreateSubsTriggerTest and access it as instance.generateTestMethod().

For example:

```
public with sharing class AutoCreateSubsTriggerTest {

    static testMethod void testAutoCreateSubs() {
        User testUser = generateTestUser();
        // your code
    }

    private static User generateTestUser(){
        // your code
    }
}
```

Note the `static` keyword between `private` and `User`. Also note, you can only make a variable or method 'static' if it is at the top level, i.e. you cannot make a method or variable static if it is a child/nested class.

Comment: Yes, this should be a static method. Sorry I missed that when I originally wrote that stuff up in the other question @Zoom_v.

Comment: aah, shameful attempt by me to score booty - not even OP's own code :)

Comment: dumb rookie question : How can I do that in this code ? I notice it would be within another static method. Sorry, that's probably a very dumb question.

Comment: no probs, there are no dumb questions @Zoom_v. Updated my answer to illustrate.

Comment: I get a : "Save error: Only top-level class variables can be declared static" now that I put that line in. Also : Should that last curly bracket just go all the way to the bottom of the code to encompass everything below it ? 

Thanks a ton @PhilHawthorn

Comment: @JesseAltman : I'm sorry for bringing this code to a whole different question. I just figured you had abandoned that other one because I had showed you some code regarding changing that code from an insert to an upsert but didn't hear back from ya.

Comment: If your class is structured as per latest edit, you shouldn't get that. You will only get that if your Test class is nested within another class

Comment: @Zoom_v it is no problem. Not a big deal. I didn't get a chance to go back over it, things got busier for me lol...

Comment: @PhilHawthorn I'm confused right now because I'm getting a "Method does not exist or incorrect signature" error on another line. I updated my original post just to show you what the code looks like right now to make sure I've done what you suggested properly. 

Thanks for any help you can give. I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Should be `System.assert(1 == subs.size(), 'One sub object is expected');`. The bottom lines are fine.

Comment: @PhilHawthorn - That did it. Thanks so much Phil !

Answer (score 2):

Use System.assertEquals() instead of System.assert(). See the [System methods documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_system.htm).

To fix the other problem, try decorating your class with an [@isTest](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm) annotation. That will help with your code coverage and code limits as well.